# Git for Windows -- Git Bash Here... -- creates .git/config

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am using Git for Windows 2.5.1 under Windows 7 x64.

I am experiencing a strange phenomenon, that is...

...whenever I use Right-Click / Git Bash Here... on a plain directory that is not under the control of git (i.e. there is no .git directory present), a new subdirectory .git gets automatically created (with a file "config" in it), however, no git command has been issued.

I went into my registry settings and I found that the "Git Bash Here..." shortcut translates into "git-bash.exe" "--cd %v".

My question is as follows: is there any way to tell "git-bash.exe" * NOT * to create any .git folder (at least not as long as no git command is issued)

The problem is that I use "Git Bash Here..." all over the place, even for directories that are not under the control of git, and what happens is that my harddisk is now littered with many empty, useless .git directories.

I was thinking, maybe there is an additional option to prevent the creation of .git/config ?

Maybe `git-bash.exe --cd %v --do-not-create-git-config` ?

Any ideas ?

Comment: why are you using git-bash here on non git stuff? to just get a bash shell at that location?

Comment: I usually have a parent directory that is not under the control of git, I use Right-Click / Git Bash Here.. into that parent directory, then I cd into one of the many sub-directories, the sub directories are, of course, under git, i.e a directory /.git is present in each sub directory, and that is ok -- however, what is not ok is that a new .git directory has automatically been created in the parent directory

Comment: Sounds strange. Im using git for few years never heard of it before.

Comment: maybe you have some other git extensions? turtoiseGit?

Comment: Just as an additional information: Under the old MSysGit for Windows, that problem did not occur, i.e. I could Git Bash Here... into any directory of my choice, and, as long as I did not issue a git init command, no /.git got created -- the problem started with the new Git for Windows

Comment: I don't have turtoise git

Comment: Do you have some bash profile somewhere?

Comment: @poke -- Thanks for your question -- That's it, -- in my ".bashrc" I had a left-over from last week's testing: --  "git config color.diff auto" -- I had forgotten to remove that line. -- In fact, when I remove the "git config color.diff auto", everything goes back to normal -- Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @poke's comment

In fact, in my ".bashrc" I had a left-over from last week's testing: "git config color.diff auto"

I had forgotten to remove that line.

When I remove the "git config color.diff auto", everything goes back to normal

Problem solved

Comment: Sometimes it’s the most obvious thing—glad you got it solved :)